# Fill gap in Panda's dataframe with repeated values

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like the following

```
timestamp   v
1           5
2           6
6           7
8           8
```

Is there a way in Pandas to create a dataframe that completes the missing *timestamp* and uses the last assigned values of *v* without having to iterate between each line?

```
timestamp   v
1           5
2           6
3           6
4           6
5           6
6           7
7           7
8           8
```

I was able to solve it by iterating between the lines and detecting the missing values in the *timestamp* and adding the last value of *v* but it is too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge_asof`:

```
# consider `pd.date_range` to generate range of timestamps
all_time = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':np.arange(df.timestamp.iloc[0], 
                                               df.timestamp.iloc[-1]+1)
                        })
pd.merge_asof(all_time, df, on='timestamp', direction='backward')
```

Output:

```
   timestamp  v
0          1  5
1          2  6
2          3  6
3          4  6
4          5  6
5          6  7
6          7  7
7          8  8
```

Comment: Just a question(since last month when I was entering in the world of pandas you answered my query and inspired me to learn pandas).  Won't creating a new df(all_time) and using merge_asof be an overhead, in terms of memory and time complexity. Also,  merge_asof is a costly operation.

Comment: @Uts in terms of memory, this is not much different from your approach. Both creates a copy of the old data. In fact, your approach copies the data several times (`set_index` then `reindex`, then `reset_index`...). This being more efficient in the sense that you would get to keep the original datatype of `v` withouth converting back and forth. The actual performance, re: `merge_asof` is costly, needs to be tested. I doubt that it would be much slower than `reindex`, if it actually is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried both approaches with 1M data and two columns. I had forgotten to write that I might need more columns like v, but both approaches work if I have more columns.  The merge_asof approach seems to be faster. I ran a few times in Google Colab and on average it gave me 140ms and with reindex 290ms.

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index[0], 1+df.index[-1])).ffill().reset_index().astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
    timestamp   v
0   1           5
1   2           6
2   3           6
3   4           6
4   5           6
5   6           7
6   7           7
7   8           8
```

**Explanation**

We are setting the index to timestamp, then we are reindexing the index based on first and last value of index and then forward fill the values.